# Run time C++ array initialization question

Tags: c++, c

Why can't we initialize array size using non-const size in global area....outside main() ....

```
//outside main - global
int val=5;
int arr[val];

int main()
{

}
```

this gives error

```
7:12: error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token
 In function 'int main()':
```

But if i move this same code inside main/body of function error disappears....

there is no error and it compiles fine...

```
int main()
{
   int val=5;
   int arr[val];
}
```

Also this works fine inside body of a function

```
void fn(int val)
{
    int arr[val];
}

int main()
{

fn(5);

}
```

Confused and how does moving array size can't be intialized only outside main?

Comment: c++ not support dynamic array declare, you need to use `int* arr = new int(val)`.

Comment: You can't use a variable length array (VLA) in standard C++ like you can in C (though G++ allows it as an extension).  Even in C, you can't have variable length arrays defined at file scope. And you cannot initialize a VLA in C at all — though your code doesn't attempt to initialize a VLA, so it isn't clear that you're using the standard term 'initialize' in the usual way. Your function `fn` doesn't do anything with the VLA; the compiler would probably elide the array (though you might not get the error you should if you pass a negative or zero value for `val` if the array was optimized away).

Comment: Just use `std::vector` instead with `c++`.

Comment: @suzuiyue: you've defined a pointer to a single integer initialized to `val`, haven't you?  I think the equivalent C++ would be more like `int *arr = new int[val];` to define an array of `val` integers — assuming you use `new` (or rather `new[]`) at all. Modern C++ would discourage all those notations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first sample, at file scope

> ```
> int val=5;
> int arr[val];
>
> int main()
> ```

is illegal on both C and C++.  Variables at file scope must be defined (created) before their first use, and continue to exist until the program ends - which also means that, once created, an array cannot be resized.  In the case of arrays, this means (among other things) that their dimension must be known at compile time.   Using a variable as an array dimension runs afoul of the need for the size of a static to be known at compile time - for example, the value of `val` could be changed at run time (e.g. in `main()`) which will be AFTER `arr` is created.

The second example

> ```
> void fn(int val)
> {
>      int arr[val];
> }
> ```

is legal in C (from 1999), because `arr` is of automatic (not static) storage duration.   It will be created when the function body is entered, and cease to exist when the function returns.    This is called a "variable length array" or VLA, because the number of elements is determined by a value of a variable (`val`) at run time.

VLAs were also not supported before the 1999 C standard.

In C++, VLAs are illegal.   Period.   However, some C++ compilers do support such a feature as a non-standard extension.    In C++, rather than using arrays, a standard container (e.g. `std::vector<int>`) is preferred for various reasons, including ability to resize it at run time.

Answer (score 3):

For the array inside function:

you are relying on GCC extension, if you add -pedantic you will get this warning:

> warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'arr' [-Wvla]

So C++ does not support variable length arrays, suggested alternative is std::vector.

For the array outside function:

you need to add const before int. Yes I know compiler could in theory figure out that val is never changed, but for some reason(nobody thought to add that to standard, or there are good reasons not to do it) you are required to add const.